# can we add direct bootstap template to our spring mvc app?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

i have downloaded  template & add all of template file in "/WebContent" folder.but when template index.jsp file open it will show no css content/styling (i have change template index.html to index.jsp). & welcome page is template index.jsp

[image: project directory]

> spring+hibenate.xml

```
    <!-- Add AspectJ autoproxy support for AOP -->
    <aop:aspectj-autoproxy/>

    <!-- Add support for component scanning -->
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.Restaurant" />

    <!-- Add support for conversion, formatting and validation support -->
    <mvc:annotation-driven/>

    <!-- Define Spring MVC view resolver -->
    <bean
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/view/" />
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
    </bean>

    <!-- loading custome messages resource -->
    <bean id="messageSource" class="org.springframework.context.support.ResourceBundleMessageSource">       
        <!-- where to find properties file -->
        <property name="basenames" value="Resources/messages" />
    </bean>

    <!-- Step 1: Define Database DataSource / connection pool -->
    <bean id="myDataSource" class="com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource"
          destroy-method="close">
        <property name="driverClass" value="com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver" />
        <property name="jdbcUrl" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3300/restaurant?useSSL=false&amp;serverTimezone=UTC" />
        <property name="user" value="root" />
        <property name="password" value="safwan" /> 

        <!-- these are connection pool properties for C3P0 -->
        <property name="minPoolSize" value="5" />
        <property name="maxPoolSize" value="20" />
        <property name="maxIdleTime" value="30000" />
    </bean>  
    
    <!-- Step 2: Setup Hibernate session factory -->    
    <bean id="sessionFactory"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="myDataSource" />                   <!-- ref to DB in step 1 -->
        <property name="packagesToScan" value="com.Restaurant.Entity" />
        <property name="hibernateProperties">
           <props>
              <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</prop>
              <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
           </props>
        </property>
   </bean>    

    <!-- Step 3: Setup Hibernate transaction manager -->
    <bean id="myTransactionManager"
            class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.HibernateTransactionManager">
        <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory"/>
    </bean>
    
    <!-- Step 4: Enable configuration of transactional behavior based on annotations -->
    <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="myTransactionManager" />

</beans>
```

> controller

```
    package com.Restaurant.Controller;

import java.lang.ProcessBuilder.Redirect;
import java.util.List;

import javax.validation.Valid;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.beans.propertyeditors.StringTrimmerEditor;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.validation.BindingResult;
import org.springframework.web.bind.WebDataBinder;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.DeleteMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.InitBinder;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ModelAttribute;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;

import com.Restaurant.Entity.Employee;
import com.Restaurant.Service.EmployeeService;

@Controller
@RequestMapping("/employee")
public class EmployeeController {
    
    @Autowired
    private EmployeeService employeeService;
    
    // for trimming white space 
    @InitBinder
    public void initBinder(WebDataBinder binder) {
        StringTrimmerEditor editor=new StringTrimmerEditor(true);
        binder.registerCustomEditor(String.class, editor);
    }
    
    
    @GetMapping("/list")
    public String listEmployee(Model model) {
            
        
        List<Employee> employees = employeeService.getEmployees();
        
        model.addAttribute("employees", employees);
        
        return "list-employee";
    }
    
    
    @GetMapping("/addEmployee")
    public String addEmployee(Model model) {
        
        Employee employee=new Employee();
        
        // empty object is passed for binding employee object to input field
        model.addAttribute("employee", employee);
        
        return "add-employee";
    }
    
    
    @PostMapping("/validateEmployee")
    public String validateEmployee(@Valid @ModelAttribute Employee employee, BindingResult bindingResult) {
        
        System.out.println(bindingResult);
        
        if(bindingResult.hasErrors()) {
            return "add-employee";
        }else {
            employeeService.saveOrEdit(employee);
            return "redirect:/employee/list";
        }
    }
    
    @GetMapping("/edit")
    public String editEmployee(@RequestParam("employeeId") int empId, Model model ) {
        
        Employee employee = employeeService.getEmployee(empId);
        
        // to prefill input field, which is done automatically by 'modelAttribute' & <form: form> tag       
        model.addAttribute("employee", employee);
        
        return "add-employee";
    }
    
    @GetMapping("/delete")
    public String deleteEmployee(@RequestParam("employeeId") int empId, Model model) {
        
        employeeService.deleteEmployee(empId);
        
        return "redirect:list";         // "redirect:list"  it is same as "redirect:/employee/list"
    }
    
}
```

now i have used templates "index.jsp" as my welcome-page but when it will open it does not show any styling

> index.jsp

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <title>Feliciano - Free Bootstrap 4 Template by Colorlib</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Poppins:100,200,300,400,500,600,700,800,900" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Great+Vibes&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/open-iconic-bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/animate.css">
    
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/owl.carousel.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/owl.theme.default.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/magnific-popup.css">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/aos.css">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/ionicons.min.css">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap-datepicker.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/jquery.timepicker.css">

    
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/flaticon.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/icomoon.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
  </head>
```

> /Restaurant/src/Resources/messages.properties

```
typeMismatch.employee.age= Invalid age
```

Comment: Show us your mvcconfig (xml/java) if any. Also show your controller and application.properties/yml. Need to see how all these are wired to suggest better. Straight forwardedly putting a downloaded template wouldnt work as you need to fix all those relative paths to your css/font/jsfiles etc

Comment: Please can you provide solution for this problem,

Comment: i got an answer, just we have to write following code in spring xml , <mvc:resources mapping="/css/**" location="/css/" />

Comment: You can take a look at this- https://github.com/ajkr195/springbootrocks and this -https://github.com/ajkr195/springbootrocks/blob/master/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/fragments/header.jspf